# Transfer Function of a boost converter

Tags: control

Need help deriving a boost converter transfer function

Design Specs:

- Input Voltage = 3.3V
- Output Voltage = 5V
- Output Current = 2.5A
- Voltage Ripple = 0.1V
- Load = 2 ohms
- Switching Frequency = 31250hz

The simulation resulted in

- Output voltage of around 4V
- and an output current around 2A

[image]

Here is the schematic in which I used
[image]

Here is the ODE:

\$d(C\dot V_c-C\ddot V_c)+C\ddot
   V_c+\frac{V_c}{L}(1-d)-\frac{V_{IN}}{L}+\frac{V_C}{L}d+\frac{\dot
   V_C}{R}(1-d)=0\$

I get stuck on getting the above ODE into laplace domain, if anyone can shed some light that would be great

The Output is: \$V_C\$
and the input is: d

in terms of \$H(s)=\frac{V_C}{d}\$

Comment: What component values did you use to produce your waveform analysis? The circuit you show has no component values.

Answer (score 2):

To determine the transfer function of a switching converter, there are different ways. The state space averaging technique or SSA has been introduced by Dr. Cuk in 1976 and heavily uses matrix analysis. The principle is to weight the coefficients describing the circuit on- and off-states by \$D\$ and \$(1-D)\$ to form a time-continuous nonlinear equation. You then need to linearize this expression and assemble a canonical model. Then, you can apply your favorite tools to determine the control-to-output transfer function of your choice. The problem with the SSA is that it models the entire converter: should you want to add a front-end filter or add a parasitic term to the capacitor or the inductor, you have to restart from scratch.

In 1986, Dr. Vorpérian came up with the PWM switch model, an elegant way to model the switching cell alone, leaving the rest of the elements untouched. The cell is invariant and can be plugged in any 2-switch converter. The original paper is available [here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/106126/) and an introduction with associated auto-toggling DCM-CCM models is described [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071823468). The principle is easy, identify the switching cell and replace the symbol by the linearized PWM switch as shown below:

[image]

The recent APEC 2018 seminar "Closing the Feedback Loop through Simulation and Analysis" available [here](http://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202018.pdf) shows how to determine the control-to-output transfer function of the boost converter operated in voltage mode. The expression features a LHP zero and a RHP zero. The denominator is a of second order in continuous conduction mode or CCM. It is determined in the PPT using the fast analytical circuits techniques or [FACTs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1119236371):

[image]

Should you want to determine the function, you have all the elements to give a try and even explore the discontinuous mode of operation (DCM) if you want.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have a question about linearity, you said I would have to make it linear, however how is it not linear? I get the PWM is not linear but I mean oppose to this for example, the buck converter's ODE is linear [Buck Converter ODE](https://youtu.be/aa5M1HiM7Ac?t=5m37s).

The way I see non-linearity is through these rules [ODE non linear](https://www.myphysicslab.com/explain/classify-diff-eq-en.html)

Comment: So essentially it's the same thing as doing small signal analysis on a mosfet, where you replace it with a current source and RDS

Comment: The SSA gives a nonlinear time-continuous equation. As you multiply variables together, this is nonlinear and must be linearized. Honestly, SSA for switching converters is a complex option and I can only recommend to use the PWM switch for the purpose of determining control-to-output transfer functions. Furthermore, the PWM switch gets the real answer while SSA, in some cases, cannot predict the RHPZ in DCM or the fact that a DCM-operated converter is still an overdamped 2nd order system. So go for the PWM switch and stay away from SSA : )

Comment: You got it boss, however with the PWM switch model is that a transformer, I no longer understand how I would achieve the equations from Nodal analysis

Comment: It is difficult to explain in a few lines... The 1:D dc transformer represents the *averaged* switching cell. That is to say, "secondary" current and voltage are linked with the "primary" current and voltage by \$D\$. You obtain this invariant relationship through averaging as described in the PPT I linked.

Comment: I wouldnt know how to model this now:( the articles posted can you maybe lead where they get an ODE from the model?

Comment: @VerbalKint Hi, In the above comment that you posted, you gave the transfer function Vout(s)/D(s) where, I suppose, D is equal to the duty cycle. In your book, "Switch mode Power supplies - Spice simulations and design", the same transfer function appears, nevertheless it is equal to Vout(s)/Verr(s) which is from my mind not the same things as the controller chip modify the transfer function, isn't it ? Btw, There is something that I do not understand, all the transfer function are given in CCM or DCM and in function of the topology but thet do not depends on the controller chip...

Comment: I would have though that the controller chip would have an influence on the transfer function

Comment: Yes, what matters is the pulse-width modulator (PWM) gain which produces the duty ratio \$D\$ based on the error voltage \$V_{err}\$. In the above example, if you want to determine \$\frac{V_{out}}{V_{err}}\$ you need to divide \$H_0\$ by \$V_p\$ where \$V_p\$ is the peak voltage of the modulator sawtooth. If this peak is 2 V, then it brings a 6-dB attenuation. If this peak voltage value is 1 V, then the transfer function is the same.

Comment: Ok thank you ! Everything is clear ! I did not pay attention to the difference between the different static gains ! My bad !